# Can voltage be controlled in a fixed DC circuit?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current

If resistance is fixed in a DC circuit, can voltage still be controlled and changed from one value to another?

Imagine this circuit, that has a fixed resistance of 1 Ohm, and the desired current is 20A, If the power supply is 100W, what would the voltage be? 5V?
If so, what about ohms law? V = IR? And P = IV?

I'm confused because I thought that voltage and current can be controlled to whatever value required, using a power supply. The resistance of the circuit is the most important thing isn't it?

Another example: 
A 20,000W power-source, and the resistance of the circuit is fixed at 0.001 Ohms, can the power supply control the voltage to any value required? 2V, 10,000A? Or any other combination that does not exceed 20,000W? 20,000V at 1A? The same resistance of 0.001 Ohms?

Comment: The power supply can supply up to 100W. If you want 20A through 1 Ohm, you need 20 V (and the power dissipated would be 400W, so this power supply won't cut it).

Comment: Think of a human as a power supply to a bike. They can produce up to some maximum power, but only at some suitable range of torques (read voltage) and current (read rpm). Any given power supply has some operating range, you can't just pick a voltage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually power supplies are designed to try to output a constant voltage (to approximate an ideal voltage source). If the resistance is also constant then you can predict the current from Ohm's law. Usually if a wattage is specified, that's a maximum input or output wattage.

It's also possible to design a power supply that attempts to output a constant current or even a constant power, but that's not the norm.

If the load resistance is too low for the constant voltage supply, or too high for a constant current it won't be able to deliver the set voltage or current. Constant power is a bit more tricky because if the load is too *low* resistance or too *high* resistance it won't be able to deliver the desired power (it will run into a current limitation at the low resistance end and a voltage limitation at the high resistance end).

Comment: Well, ideally in this example I used, I need to add an additional 300W to have 20A of current. But what about having a different circuit that could manipulate the input power of (100W) and make it 20A at 5V? 100W at 1 Ohms = 10V x 10A, what about using a converter, a step down converter that reduces voltage while it increases the current? But that is kinda counter intuitive, I need high voltage for that massive current or...?

Comment: An ideal **switching regulator** could take input power at one voltage and produce a different voltage and current subject to the limitation power out = power in. So 100W in at a given voltage could become 10V at 10A or 100V at 1A. Of course in reality there are some losses..maybe 10-15%,

Comment: Independent of the load resistance? Still such a regulator can apply varying voltages?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put 20A through the resistor, since this would require \$20\text{A}\times1\Omega = 20\text{V}\$ and hence a \$20\text{A}\times20\text{V}=400\text{W}\$ power supply.

The most current you can put through the resistor is \$\sqrt{100\text{W} \over 1\Omega} = 10\text{A}\$. Any deviation above or below \${100\text{W} \over 10\text{A}} = 10\text{V}\$ will cause a lower current to flow due to the limit of the supply and the limit provided by Ohm's Law. Note that only part of the voltage will be dropped by the resistor if it varies above 10V, and the power supply will have to drop the rest internally.

Comment: Can there be a circuit design to keep the current the same at 20A with 5V? Maybe using step-up/down converters connected to the 100W supply? I'm thinking of other possible methods without adding 300W if there are any.

Comment: You have a 1ohm resistor. To put 20A through it you need 20V. You can't get past Ohm's Law. And you only have a 100W power supply. No amount of boost/buck can change that.

Comment: Ah you right, but if I wanted higher voltage and lower current that can be easily done with a dc/dc converter.

Comment: You can't get around the fact that you only have 100W going in. You can burst to 400W through the resistor, but only for 1/4 the time. The rest of the time you're building up energy and the circuit is dead.

Comment: What I mean in the previous comment is that a boost converter can change the input voltage to 20V at 5A or 50V at 2A as output, from the input 100W power source. It's not related to my previous example.

Comment: I've been going with the assumption that the supply is variable, but can only provide 100W of power. So while you can increase the voltage that it's outputting, not all of it will be dropped by the resistor. A booster doesn't change that, only what needs to drop the remaining voltage.

Comment: What do you mean that not all of it will be dropped by the resistor? And only dropping the remaining voltage?

Comment: If you put 1A through a 1ohm resistor and measure the voltage across it, you will measure 1V. If you set your supply to 3V and limit it to 1A, then the other 2V doesn't just mysteriously disappear. Either the supply will refuse to supply all 3V, or the other 2V will be dropped somewhere else.

Comment: By only providing 100W of power, I'm limited to the voltage outputted. Due to the 1ohm resistor. So it's kinda pointless to use a boost converter. So with that 1ohm resistor I can't really have 20VDC at 5A.

Answer (score 1):

> If resistance is fixed in a DC circuit, can voltage still be
>   controlled and changed from one value to another?

Yes but, since the resistance is fixed, *the current is not independent of the voltage* and, indeed, the current will be proportional to the voltage.

If the power supply can provide 100W of power, the maximum voltage it can produce across the resistor is

$$V_{max} = \sqrt{100W \cdot 1\Omega}  = 10V $$

At that voltage, the current will be

$$I_{max} = \frac{10V}{1\Omega} = 10A $$

You can put in different values for the power rating and circuit resistance to find the maximum voltage and current.

Comment: I'm trying to relate this to a step up/down converter or even constant current source or voltage source where the load "resistance" is independent. I'm also confused as to how a boost converter can take that input of 100W, and make the voltage higher than 10V of course with the current being less equaling always to 100W. Confusing, I assume the converters change the resistance?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if the resistance is 1 ohm and the desired current is 20A, then ohms law can be applied in the form: V = IR.  Thus, V = 1X20 = 20 volts.  If your power supply applies 20 volts to the 1 ohm  resistor, the current through the resistor will be 20A.  The power delivered by the power supply and dissipated in the resistor will indeed be VI = 20X20 = 400 watts. If your power supply is only able to supply 100 watts, then it won't be able to apply 20 volts across your 1 ohm resistor.  The best it might do (from 100 = V^2/R) is 10 volts. Then the current will be 10/1 = 10A and the delivered power will be 10X10 = 100 watts. In general if you have a fixed resistance load, you cannot independently specify both the voltage and current.  Ohms law says that V = IR, so if R is fixed, you can specify V or I and then calculate the other from the equation.